# Is it OK to call ensureIndex on non-existent collections?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I read somewhere that calling `ensureIndex()` actually creates a collection if it does not exist. But the index is always on some fields, not all of them, so if I ensure an index on say `{ name:1 }` and then add documents to that collection that have many more fields, the index will work? I know we don't have a schema, coming from RDBMS world I just want to make sure. :) I'd like to create indexes when my website starts, but initially the database is empty. I do not need to have any data prior to ensuring indexes, is that correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ensureIndex` will create the collection if it does not yet exist. It does not matter if you add documents that don't have the property that the index covers, you just can't use that index to find those documents. The way I understand it is that in versions before 1.7.4 a document that is missing a property for which there is an index will be indexed as though it had that property, but will a null value. In versions after 1.7.4 you can create sparse indexes that don't include these objects at all. The difference is slight but may be significant in some situations.

Depending on the circumstances it may not be a good idea to create indexes when the app starts. Consider the situation where you deploy a new version which adds new indexes when it starts up, in development you will not notice this as you only have a small database, but in production you may have a huge database and adding the index will take a lot of time. During the index creation your app will hang and you can't serve requests. You can create indexes with the background flag set to true (the syntax depends on which driver you're using), but in most cases it's better to add indexes manually, or as part of a setup script. That way you will have to think before you update indexes.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC and the official C# driver specifically, but I feel the question is technology agnostic. I haven't thought about putting the indexing calls into my build script, though, which sounds interesting, I need to find out how to call `ensureIndex` from the command line.

Comment: I think it should be possible to call `ensureIndex` from a JS script loaded through the mongo shell.

Comment: You can run a JavaScript file with `mongo db_name script.js`. That file can contain most things you can type in the Mongo console.

Answer (score 3):

> Deprecated since version 3.0: db.collection.ensureIndex() has been
> replaced by db.collection.createIndex().

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/